# Laplacian of a directed weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian, directed-graphs

I know that for a simple undirected graph $\mathcal{G}(V,E) $ the Laplacian matrix $L$ is defined as:
$$ L:=D-A$$ where $D$ is the degree diagonal matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $\mathcal{G}$.

My question is: how can I define the Laplacian for a directed weighted graph $\mathcal{G}(V,W)$ ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First let me give another common way of computing the Laplacian of an undirected graph $G=(V, E)$ that generalizes more easily to the directed weighted graphs you are interested in.

Suppose $V = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ and $E = \{1, \dots, m\}$ and fix an arbitrary orientation on the edges. Consider the *vertex space* $\mathbb{R}^V$ with standard basis $\{\mathbf{e}_1, \dots, \mathbf{e}_n\}$ and, for each edge $i \in \{1,\dots,m\}$, let $\mathbf{n}_i = \mathbf{e}_j - \mathbf{e}_k$. Then the $n \times m$ matrix $N$ whose columns are the $\mathbf{n}_i$ ($i\in[m]$) is called the *signed vertex-edge incidence matrix* of $G$ (with respect to the fixed orientation).

The key fact is that the Laplacian $L$ of the $G$ is the (transpose of the) [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of $N$, that is, $L = NN^{\top}$. In particular, the matrix product $NN^{\top}$ does not depend on the orientation we fixed.

Now let $G$ be a weighted directed graph and let $W$ be the $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with entries $W_{ij}$ equal to the weight of edge $i$ if $i=j$ and zero else. Then we can define the Laplacian of $G$ as the matrix product $NWN^{\top}$ where $N$ is the signed vertex-edge incidence matrix of the underlying unweighted graph of $G$. And this definition generalizes the case for unweighted undirected graphs. See Section 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3876.pdf) for more on the subject.

Comment: If $N$ is $n\times m$, then actually $L=NN^\top$ rather than the other way around. Despite this detail, very useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @Jonas. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This might be not actual any longer, but still... In your formulation, $G$ is a symmetric matrix, while this should not be the case for directed graphs. What would be, e.g., the difference between G for a graph 1->2->1 with weights w(1,2)=2 and w(2,1)=1 and the same graph with weights w(1,2)=3 and w(2,1)=2?

Comment: @Dmitry: $G$ is a graph and not a matrix. The Laplacian $L$ of $G$ is always symmetric in this set up and I don't see why this "should not be the case for the directed graphs". It's true that the adjacency matrix $A$ of a weighted directed graph need not be symmetric but that matrix doesn't appear in the given definition of $L$.

Comment: @AaronDall the last comment means then that the definition of the laplacian as $L = D-A$ and $L=NWN^\top$ do not coincide (i.e. it is not the same matrix?), right? With the first definition, the Laplacian is not symmetric, whereas with the second defintion, it is always symmetric.